# &#57488 character not displaying on website

Tags: html, character-encoding

Hi guys I have the code:

```
<span class="state_tiny-close-x">&#57488<!-- icon_cross --></span>
```

But I can't see the cross, how do I get this working? Do I need to include a charaset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include a `;` to finish the character reference:

```
&#57488;
```

You also need a font that includes that character.

Comment: The semicolon is recommended, but not required (except by XHTML rules, which are enforced only when the document is served with an XML content type).

Answer (score 2):

The character reference `&#57488` (which is better written with a trailing semicolon: `&#57488;`) denotes the Unicode code point U+E090. This is designated as a Private Use code point, which means that no character is assigned to it in the standard; it has a meaning only as per private agreements, and it should thus not be used in public information interchange. (The Unicode Standard, [Chapter 16](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch16.pdf), clause 16.5.)

Presumably, you are using a downloadable font via `@font-face`. Some fonts use Private Use code points for various symbols, causing failures whenever that specific font is not used.  Apparently, something goes wrong with the use of the font in this case; check the browser’s error log and network log for reasons. But the real solution is to use images rather than such font tricks. (If the symbol used has been encoded as a Unicode character, use that character, using the proper code point, and try to make sure that some properly encoded font will be used to render it.)

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the semi-colon

```
&#57488;
```